# How to remove columns from multiple files using sed?

Tags: perl, sed

How to remove columns from multiple files using sed?

input

```
1    2.1    3.3   4.2    5.1
```

output

```
3.3   4.2    5.1
```

it will be good if the output will be aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way (Output is tab-separated):

```
perl -lane'print join "\t",@F[2..$#F]' file
```

For right-aligned output:

```
perl -lane'printf "%10s",$_ for @F[2..$#F];print "";' file
```

Comment: Thanks its working. By the way how to get the results right aligned?

Comment: To get right-aligned columns, you'd use a `printf()` with an appropriate format: `%10.2f` for each field, perhaps.  This isn't a `sed` solution as requested — but `awk` or `perl` (or `python` or `ruby` or ...) probably is more sensible than `sed`.

Comment: Golf: Space-separated: `perl -pale'$_="@F[2..$#F]"' file` Tap-separated: `perl -pale'$"="\t";$_="@F[2..$#F]"' file`

Comment: I find `perl -lanE'say sprintf "%10s"x(@F-2), @F[2..$#F]' file` more readable than your right-aligned solution.

Comment: Thanks ikegami its really amazing.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed to remove first two columns:

```
sed 's/^[ \t]*[0-9.]*[ \t]*[0-9.]*[ \t]*//' input1 input2
```

You can increase the number of `[ \t]*[0-9.]*`s if you want to remove more columns.

Comment: Thanks its working. By the way how to get the results right aligned?

Comment: If you need right-aligned results, you should use `awk` or `perl`.

Comment: @user2176228, for right align use bash or perl printf. But check the output of `sed 's/^[ \t]*[0-9.]*[ \t]*[0-9.]*[ \t]*//' input | column -t` and see if you like it.

Answer (score 1):

awk can do the same allowing you to switch easily the columns and change the separator in input and output if needed:

```
awk '{print $3,$4,$5}' test
3.3 4.2 5.1
```

hope it helps

Comment: This isn't a `sed` solution as requested — but `awk` or `perl` (or `python` or `ruby` or ...) probably is more sensible than `sed`, and the alternatives seem to be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{$1=$2="";gsub("^  ","",$0);}1' your_file
```

or

```
perl -lane 'print "@F[2..scalar(@F)]"' your_file
```